# Очень странный скрипт

Tags: javascript

- Встретил очень странный код.
- Что такое **`**  и  **${ }** ?

```js
let user = {
name: "Серега",
age: 23,

[Symbol.toPrimitive](opt){
alert(`opt: ${opt}`); // За что отвечают `` ?
return opt == "string" ? `{name: "${this.name}"}` : this.age;  // А это что за конструкция ${}??
} 
};

alert(user);
alert(+user);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не писать всё время +, складывая строки с переменными

```js
const a = 2;
const b = 'привет';
const str = (a * 2) + ' ' + b + ', кожаный мешок';
const str1 = `${a * 2} ${b}, кожаный мешок`;
console.log(str);
console.log(str1);
```